# POST запрос с XML на адрес URL посредством PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, http, api, plsql, plsql-developer

Задача:
С помощью подобной процедуры направить запрос с XML-файлом вида CLOB на адрес url. В итоге с моим кодом на сайт отправляется (лог показывает, что что-то вроде пришло

```
17.12.2019 17:59:19 [IntServlet] - ***** IntServlet.doPost *****)
```

но сообщение пустое, хотя и length заполняется и p_result тоже (логами проверял) в виде XML CLOB. В итоге ни ошибок, ни данных из XML-файла.. как быть, что не так?
Сам XML такого содержания:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<record>
 <ROW>
  <ID>49732</ID>
  <FILE_ID>1565</FILE_ID>
  <LASTNAME>TINPU</LASTNAME>
  <FIRSTNAME>VOLODYA</FIRSTNAME>
  <CITIZENSHIP>RU</CITIZENSHIP>
 </ROW>
</record>
```

Рабочий, да не до конца, код:

```
procedure afl_to_akr (p_result in CLOB) is
  l_url varchar2(690);
  req   utl_http.req;
  resp  utl_http.resp;
  l_out  CLOB;
BEGIN
  l_url := 'http://10.120.48.3:8180/ab-int/integroServlet?xml=';

   req := utl_http.begin_request(url => l_url, method => 'POST', http_version => 'HTTP/1.1');                                 
   utl_http.set_header(r => req, name => 'Content-Type', value => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   utl_http.set_header(r => req, name => 'Content-Length', value => length(p_result));
   utl_http.write_text(r => req, data => p_result);

   resp := utl_http.get_response(req);   

   begin
      utl_http.read_line(resp, l_out);
      utl_http.end_response(resp);   
exception
 when utl_http.end_of_body then
  utl_http.end_response(resp);
   end;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл выход..я ключ не указывал "xml=" и в адресной строке не надо было указывать "?xml=". Однако теперь проблема в том, что русский шрифт делается знаками "???????"

```
procedure afl_to_akr(l_result in CLOB) is
  req   utl_http.req;
  res   utl_http.resp;
  l_out VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_url varchar2(690) := l_url := 'http://10.120.48.3:8180/ab-int/integroServlet';
  l_body CLOB;
begin
   req := utl_http.begin_request(l_url, 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');
   utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
   l_body := 'xml=' || l_result;      
   utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', length(l_body));
   utl_http.write_text(req, l_body);
   res := utl_http.get_response(req);
   begin
      utl_http.read_line(res, l_out);
      utl_http.end_response(res);
   exception
      when utl_http.end_of_body then
         utl_http.end_response(res);
   end;  
end;
```